# Query for missing elements

Tags: sql-server-2005, null, common-table-expression, aggregates

I have a table with the following structure:

```
timestamp | name | value
0         | john | 5
1         | NULL | 3
8         | NULL | 12
12        | john | 3
33        | NULL | 4
54        | pete | 1
180       | NULL | 4
400       | john | 3
401       | NULL | 4
592       | anna | 2
```

Now what I am looking for is a query that will give me the sum of the values for each name, and treats the nulls in between (orderd by the timestamp) as the first non-null name down the list, as if the table were as follows:

```
timestamp | name | value
0         | john | 5
1         | john | 3
8         | john | 12
12        | john | 3
33        | pete | 4
54        | pete | 1
180       | john | 4
400       | john | 3
401       | anna | 4
592       | anna | 2
```

and I would query `SUM(value), name from this table group by name`. I have thought and tried, but I can't come up with a proper solution. I have looked at recursive common table expressions, and think the answer may lie in there, but I haven't been able to properly understand those.

These tables are just examples, and I don't know the timestamp values in advance.

Could someone give me a hand? Help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: +1 for providing some sample inputs and expected outputs (although you might also include what you expect for the summed values).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
With Inputs As
    (
    Select 0 As [timestamp], 'john' As Name, 5 As value
    Union All Select 1, NULL, 3
    Union All Select 8, NULL, 12
    Union All Select 12, 'john', 3
    Union All Select 33, NULL, 4
    Union All Select 54, 'pete', 1
    Union All Select 180, NULL, 4
    Union All Select 400, 'john', 3
    Union All Select 401, NULL, 4
    Union All Select 592, 'anna', 2
    )
    , NamedInputs As
    (
    Select I.timestamp
        , Coalesce (I.Name
            ,   (
                Select I3.Name
                From Inputs As I3
                Where I3.timestamp = (
                                    Select Max(I2.timestamp)
                                    From Inputs As I2
                                    Where I2.timestamp < I.timestamp
                                        And I2.Name Is not Null
                                    )
                )) As name
        , I.value
    From Inputs As I
    )
Select NI.name, Sum(NI.Value) As Total
From NamedInputs As NI
Group By NI.name
```

Btw, what would be orders of magnitude faster than any query would be to first correct the data. I.e., update the name column to have the proper value, make it non-nullable and then run a simple Group By to get your totals.

**Additional Solution**

```
Select Coalesce(I.Name, I2.Name), Sum(I.value) As Total
From Inputs As I
    Left Join   (
                Select I1.timestamp, MAX(I2.Timestamp) As LastNameTimestamp
                From Inputs As I1
                    Left Join Inputs As I2
                        On I2.timestamp < I1.timestamp
                            And I2.Name Is Not Null   
                Group By I1.timestamp
                ) As Z
        On Z.timestamp = I.timestamp        
    Left Join Inputs As I2
        On I2.timestamp = Z.LastNameTimestamp
Group By Coalesce(I.Name, I2.Name)
```

Comment: Hi Thomas, Thanks for the answer! I suppose I should have specified in advance that this is an example, it is in fact a very large table, and I don't know the timestamp values in advance. Thanks still for getting me on track.

Comment: @Martijn - In my example, it shouldn't matter. My `Inputs` CTE is merely for testing purposes. You would only need the `NamedInputs` CTE (called whatever you like) to determine which name it should assign a NULL. I will say that if you are going to do this, a faster way would be to update the data, make the column non-nullable, and then run your sum.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood. I'll give this a run and a try on my actual data, and see how this works. Cake will be sent if it meets my needs ;)

Comment: @Martijn - I've posted another possible solution. However, I still contend that correcting the data and then querying directly against the table will be the best approach.

Comment: @Thomas, you are completely right that updating is preferable. However, this is data coming from a closed-source third party app. I'm afraid that updating will break stuff in ways that I can't anticipate. (I considered copying and updating, but we're talking about a lot off data).

Comment: @Thomas, and where you were, thinking both the cake and the getting the anwer was a lie. A Solutions copying the data and filling in the blanks turned out to be the best functioning way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need CTE, just a simple subquery.

```
select t.timestamp, ISNULL(t.name, (
    select top(1) i.name
    from inputs i
    where i.timestamp < t.timestamp
    and i.name is not null
    order by i.timestamp desc
    )), t.value
from inputs t
```

And summing from here

```
select name, SUM(value) as totalValue
from
(
    select t.timestamp, ISNULL(t.name, (
        select top(1) i.name
        from inputs i
        where i.timestamp < t.timestamp
        and i.name is not null
        order by i.timestamp desc
        )) as name, t.value
    from inputs t
) N
group by name
```

Comment: Cake meet a sledgehammer of a different color.

Comment: @Thomas - Okay I win by 1 subquery level :)

Comment: with identical results, cake will be awarded to top speed.

Comment: @Mar - Yes will be interesting to see which is faster. I hedge my bets

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm not going to be embarassed by offering you this little recursive CTE query of mine as a solution to your problem.

```
;WITH
numbered_table AS (
  SELECT
    timestamp, name, value,
    rownum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY timestamp)
  FROM your_table
),
filled_table AS (
  SELECT
    timestamp,
    name,
    value
  FROM numbered_table
  WHERE rownum = 1

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    nt.timestamp,
    name = ISNULL(nt.name, ft.name),
    nt.value
  FROM numbered_table nt
    INNER JOIN filled_table ft ON nt.rownum = ft.rownum + 1
)
SELECT *
FROM filled_table
/* or go ahead aggregating instead */
```

Comment: I'll give this a go too. I don't think it'll come out very will performancewise, but I've been wrong on that account before

Comment: @Martijn: So have I. Would be nice to know if it worked well for you in this particular case.